# Java practise exam question

Tags: java

Doing practise questions for a Java exam which have no answers (useful) I have been asked to do the following:

Write a class called `Person` with the following features:

- a `private int` called `age`;
- a `private String` called `name`;
- a constructor with a `String` argument, which initialises `name` to the received value and `age` to `0`;
- a public method `toString(boolean full)`. If `full` is `true`, then the
  method returns a string consisting of the person’s name followed by their
  age in brackets; if `full` is `false`, the method returns a string consisting of
  just the name. For example, a returned string could be `Sue (21)` or `Sue`;
- a public method `incrementAge()`, which increments age and returns the
  new age;
- a public method `canVote()` which returns `true` if `age` is `18` or more and
  `false` otherwise.

My code is as follows can someone point out any errors?

```
public class Person
{
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(String st)
    {
      name = st;
      age = 0;
    }

   public String toString(boolean full)
   {
     if(full == true)
     {
        return name + "(" + age + ")";
     }
     else
     {
        return name;
     }
   }

   public int incrementAge()
   {
      age++;
      return age;
   }

   public boolean canVote()
   {
     if(age >= 18)
     {
        return true;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any errors :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

instead of

```
if(full == true)
```

use

```
if (full)
```

and instead of

```
if(age >= 18)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

use:

```
return age >= 18
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, just wee small minor things i need to keep an eye on then.

Answer (score 15):

```
 return name + "(" + age + ")";
```

to

```
return name + " (" + age + ")";
```

Answer (score 12):

That's fine, but I would have written the last method as `return (age >= 18);`

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it's a good idea to write `toString` method with arguments - doing so you will not override the default `Object.toString` and will have no benefits from using it outside your code. For example, when outputting elements of a collection which contain `Person` won't display neither age nor name, but something like `Person@a3f33f` (default implementation).
At least provide `toString` with no arguments as well

Comment: Denisk that actually moves onto my next question, Does the Person class overload or override any methods? Briefly explain your
answer.

Comment: I was going with override until i seen your comment and would go with overload the Object.toString?

Comment: Currently you have `toString` method overloaded - thus, you actually have 2 `toString` methods - one inherited from `Object` (default no-arg method), and one with `boolean` argument. If you declared your `toString` with no arguments it would override `Object.toString`, and you would end up with 1 `toString` method (which, as I have mentioned, can be widely used by many things outside your own code)

Comment: I agree with denisk, and want to point out that flags like `full` in method arguments are a code smell: A method should do one and only one thing (Single Responsibility Principle), and a method with a flag does at least two things. Uncle Bob agrees as well (Clean Code: http://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882 )

Comment: The `toString(boolean)` method is part of the assignment requirements. But normally, this is good advice.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is almost fine. I would change two things:

The following is a little shorter :)

```
public boolean canVote()
{
    return age >= 18;
}
```

Your `toString(true)` would return `"Sue(21)"` rather than the `"Sue (21)"` (with space) which is asked for. My toString would look like this:

```
public String toString(boolean full)
{
    String str = name;
    if(full) {
       str += " (" + age + ")";
    }

    return str;     
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

If the age is implemented as a primitive integer there is no need to initialize it to 0 because all primitive number instance variables are initialized to 0 by default. Anyway if you had used a wrapper instead (Integer) the initialization to 0 is required.

Take a look at the "**Default Values**" section:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other comments, on your constructor, having an argument called "st" isn't particularly useful to the reader as it doesn't tell them what it's for.  From a code style perspective might be better to have an argument called name, and explicitly set `this.name = name` in the body.

Comment: To add on, at this moment of learning it may seem not to matter, but when you're developing, these little things that make the usage more intuitive (especially when you're using auto-completion) will reduce your (and others') pain.

Answer (score 4):

How about adding a constant for 18, say MIN_AGE_TO_VOTE?

And:

```
return name + (full ? " (" + age + ")" : "");
```

Less readable, I agree :-)

Comment: +1 for only the constant. (I agree, the ternary operator is not too readable and harder to maintain.)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead of string concatenation:
<del>return name + "(" + age + ")";</del> becomes

```
return String.format("%s (%s)", name, age);
```

Comment: It's a Java question ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. The name field could be `final`. Making a variable final relieves the programmer of excess mental juggling - he/she doesn't have to scan through the code to see if the variable has changed. (From [@nerdytenor's answers.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/98796/36726))
2. You should check the argument in the constructor. Does it make sense to create a `Person` object with a name which is `null` or an empty String? If not, check it and throw a `NullPointerException` or an `IllegalArgumentException`. (*Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 38: Check parameters for validity*)
3. A note about the specification:

   > Flag arguments are ugly. Passing a boolean into a function is a truly terrible practice. It
   >   immediately complicates the signature of the method, loudly proclaiming that this function
   >   does more than one thing. It does one thing if the flag is true and another if the flag is false!

   Source: *Clean Code by Robert C. Martin, Chapter 3: Functions.*

   This should be two methods: `toString()` and `toFullString()`, for example, without any parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine, only canVote is maybe a bit clumsy:

```
   public boolean canVote()
   {
        return age >= 18;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would see if you can make the code less verbose.

```
public boolean canVote() {
    return age >= 18;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is also less verbose

```
public int incrementAge() {
  return ++age;
}
```

Comment: I worry that a student might be docked points for readability if they put that answer. Otherwise, I would write it like that too.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Person(String st)
{
  name = st;
  age = 0;
}
```

`st` is not a good name for a variable or parameter, because it does not tell you what it contains. It implies that it means "string", but even that is not clear. Call it `name` instead. Use `this.name = name` to distinguish member and parameter names.

---

Put the opening brackets on the first line of the block, not at the beginning of the next line, since it is common practise in Java (even though I find it prettier if it is on the next line, since I code C# more than Java). Other Java developers reading your code will be used to it.

---

Others have already pointed it out: Write `if (full)` instead of `if (full == true)`. That is clearer and easier to read. You can use the ternary operator for a one liner:

`return full ? name + "(" + age + ")" : name;`.

---

Your `incrementAge()` looks fine.

---

```
   public boolean canVote()
   {
     if(age >= 18)
     {
        return true;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
   }
```

Your indentation is weird. Use 4 spaces (less common tabs with width of 4 spaces) for indentation. You have sometimes 3 spaces, sometimes 2.

Since `age >= 18` is a boolean expression, you can return the result just like this:

`return age >= 18;`

Use spaces after `if` and `for` (also `while` and similar) keywords. That makes the code clearer and more readable:

```
if (someCondition) {
    doThis();
}
```